# How to reset session of CAS using selenium

Tags: ruby, cookies, selenium, selenium-webdriver, session-cookies

My app has CAS login. When I login with CAS and find out all cookies using selenium by `page.driver.browser.manage.all_cookies` it return only one cookie of app. not return cookies of CAS.

When I goto FF by

```
Edit > Preference > remove individual cookies
```

There is three cookies two of CAS and one is app.

When I run `page.driver.browser.manage.delete_all_cookies` it delete only app cookies not CAS cookies.

Is it possible to delete CAS cookies which is not coming with `page.driver.browser.manage.all_cookies`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = page.driver.browser.manage.all_cookies
```

All the browser cookies will be stored in the variable `a` as hash.

```
a.each do |cookie|
  page.driver.browser.delete_cookie(cookie)
end
```

Try this